# Keep the order of current and future posts

Tags: database

One of my curiosities these days is how to order some posts. I will give you a clear example, maybe one the majority of you experimented in the past.

The **Facebook Timeline**, which you can add posts and events to, at any point in time you want. In this case, I assume, the posts are ordered by the date. When you add a new status for the past, you have to assign it a date, so it is easy to get them in order.

What I want to do is to have posts and the option to add a new post after a specific one. I don't have the option to add a date to it but I have to have a way to get them in that order.

So, if every post has an id and a date (the creation date). If a new post is added between 2 posts, I can't increment all the ids of the "upper" posts, so that I can order by the id. Neither is the date, because I can add a post between two older posts in the future.

What solution do you imagine for this? What criteria should I order by (I am ready to make some database scheme changes if needed)?

Comment: "i don't have the option to add a date to it" to what? New Post?

Comment: @SamiAkram Yes. Maybe I was not very clear in that statement. What I meant is that I cannot have a date, like Facebook Timeline assigns to a post, and consider it the criteria that I should order by. Because the order by the date is not the same as the order I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there's another possible solution. Use two columns for ordering: `Order1` is basic order, and `Order2` is order within group defined by `Order1`. You assign your posts to some arbitrary groups (i.e. all posts from single day or every 100 posts) by setting `Order1`. Within each group posts are ordered according to value in `Order2`.

If a new post must be inserted into some group you only need to renumber `Order2` values for posts in this particular group - not all posts in table.

Of course when retrieving the rows you `order by Order1, Order2`.

So your table looks like this:

```
PostName  Order1  Order2
------------------------
A         1       1
B         1       2
C         1       3
D         1       4
E         2       1
F         2       2
G         2       3
```

Now if you want to insert `X` between `F` and `G` you renumber only items in group `Order1 = 2`, so that rows become:

```
PostName  Order1  Order2
------------------------
A         1       1
B         1       2
C         1       3
D         1       4
E         2       1
F         2       2
G         2       4
X         2       3
```

Now, if you want to insert `Z` between `A` and `B` you only renumber `Order2` in posts in group `Order1 = 1`:

```
PostName  Order1  Order2
------------------------
A         1       1
B         1       3
C         1       4
D         1       5
E         2       1
F         2       2
G         2       4
X         2       3
Z         1       2
```

Comment: And if I want to post something between A and B ? This only lets one level of "Insert-between"

Comment: If you want to insert between `A` and `B` you only renumber posts in group `Order1 = 1` and there is no need to touch rows in other groups.

Answer (score 1):

IF you're not going order  by a criteria (`Date`, for example), you will need something to order them. Not necessary have to use column Id to order, you could add a column that is not the `PK`, and makes the function of `ordinalPosition`.

So, when you insert at the end, you will get the max `ordinalPosition`, and then do ordinalPosition+1.
If you want to insert between two of those, then you look the ordinal position of the two post you have (to insert between them), update incrementing in 1 all ordinalColumns, from the major of those two post, and then (now you got a "hole" in the `ordinalPosition`),  insert the new ordinalPosition, and that will be the the minor of those two post + 1 (which equally the mayor of those two post)

Then, you will get the posts ordered by your ordinalPosition:

```
    Select fields from Posts 
 -- where  your criteria goes here
    order by ordinalPosition
```

Maybe you consider that's not a good way, because everytime you insert a post between two another one, you will have to do an update - but the Db is not magic, has to order by some criteria. And have to make sure there is no posts with same order id, so probably will have to add some Unique Constraint or something as you want.
You're not gonna update very old posts probably, so I don't think will be so much update's everytime you add a posts between other two.

Comment: isn't it a too expensive operation to increment all the posts that follow the one I want to insert after?

Comment: maybe, it will depends of how many posts you have to "move" when insert a posts between another posts. If you have 200000000 posts, and have to insert a posts between the first and the second, then yes. If you use another options, like leave space between posts, you will have a limit of posts that you can insert between another two, so I'll say it will depends of your needs. How often you're gonna insert posts between another two ? And where you're gonna insert them ? Between the last one's or the first?

Comment: I don't know this now. It all depends on the user. It can be at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end. It all depends on them.

Comment: Well, so you gonna have to decide. Think that if you're gonna put a limit, need to be a big one - What will happen if you reach that limit ? You will have to think about your app, the users you estimate you're gonna have, and how they're gonna post. Maybe the option of living some space between - but you will reach a limit of the column of total posts more quickly. Think, you leave a space of 10 between post. So, in 3 posts, you have the number 30. The number of field (if is an int) has a limit, so you will reach this limit 10 times faster. How many posts do you expect to reach ?

Comment: I think you'll need to estimate how much will grow your app before choose a model.

Comment: There is no need to renumber all posts. Please look at my other answer.